# How to switch to another user from SSH?

Tags: shell-script

I am looking for a command to SSH to a server using `root` and then switch it to other user after executing SSH. Could someone please help me in providing the command for this.

Not Working:

```
ssh root@hostname `su - dba`
```

Working:

```
ssh root@hostname (prompting for password)
```

Comment: Why does `ssh dba@hostname` not work for your needs?

Comment: Your question sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Can you tell us what problem you're trying to solve by sshing as root and then changing user?

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question correctly I believe you are asking how to force a pseudo-tty allocation when opening the ssh connection.

this should do what you want :

```
ssh -t root@hostname 'su - dba'
```

Not sure why you need that....